# Parse xml label with properties

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have from a xml api this:

```
<artist>    
  <name>David Guetta & Afrojack</name>
  <url>http://www.last.fm/music/David+Guetta+&+Afrojack</url>
  <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/67755308.jpg</image>
  <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/67755308.jpg</image>
</artist>
```

I parse the name and url to PHP in this way:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('api.xml');
$name=$xml->artist->name;
$url=$xml->artist->url;
```

How do I get the url of the image in medium size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the attribute `size` on the `image` elements.

```
foreach($xml->artist->image as $image) {
    if((string)$image['size'] == 'medium') {
        $image = (string)$image;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to loop through all of the attributes in the `image` elements you can do this.

```
foreach($xml->artist->image as $image) {
    foreach($image->attributes() as $key => $value) {
        if($value == 'medium') {
          $image = (string)$image;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the array-notation as described in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) (example 5):

```
$size = (string) $xml->artist->image['size'];
```